# Fopen() return false

Tags: php, fopen

```
$mId = 36008;
$path = "message/piece_jointe/$mId/test-fo.pdf"; 
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
```

$fp return false. However when i omit $mid ih the path variable it works fine. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: And what is the question now?

Comment: How to make it work and not return false instead.

Comment: *However when i omit $mid ih the path variable it works fine* <- You answered your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have "message/piece_jointe/36008/" directory, you have to use "mkdir" first as fopen doesn't create the directories if they do not exist

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$mId = 36008;
$filename = "test-fo.pdf";
$directory = "message/piece_jointe/$mId/";
$path = $directory.$filename; 
if (!is_dir($directory)) {
    mkdir($directory);
}
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute path with `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` if you have an older version. Be patient if you replace a part of your path with variables. This could give some security problems.